# Modern alternative to TRIAC for switching alternating current?

Tags: mosfet, solid-state-relay, triac

The only alternative I know is a high power MOSFET wrapped with diode bridge.

Comment: That, or series connected and opposite MOSFETs or IGBTs.

Comment: Geez, could you spend just a little more effort in asking a decent question. There are more solutions but you have to find them yourself. Hint: optically isolated devices.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because users should put forth more effort into writing a question.

Comment: Is there a problem with triacs? MOSFETs are usually best at low voltages and high frequencies, IGBTs at highish voltages, large currents and medium frequencies while triacs and thyristors/SCRs are ideal for really high voltages, mind boggling currents and low frequencies (they are also the most rugged of the three). Each has it's own niche application set - although we are seeing more and mre overlap nowadays.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

An SSR (solid state relay) doesn't need a bridge: -

[image]

It handles AC and DC very nicely without using a bridge rectifier.

Comment: I've just looked some catalogs and found that most of high-current (15-20A) relays are still thyristor-based.

Comment: That doesn't surprise me although over the coming years this will become more aligned with MOSFETs with the really high power stuff remaining as IGBT technology.